# Two Connection Names in CRMA Output

Tags: standard-objects, einstein-analytics, update, crm-analytics

Has anyone experienced where there are two connection names in an output connector for an object? I'm specifically looking at the Opportunity Object in this case. Output connection name shows up as TCRM_Integration_User or TCRM_Integration_User_Opportunity in both Production and UAT.

I'm having to use the connection name TCRM_Integration_User in Production and then TCRM_Integration_User_Opportunity in UAT. I was using the TCRM_Integration_User connection name for this output connection in UAT, but found that rows were not updating until I swapped to the other.

Does anyone know why there would be two different connection names?